# Goal Conversion in Analytics - Convert only if coming from a certain page

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

On my home page (/) I have a form embedded on it. When you complete it and press submit, it takes you to a thank you page.

I also have another form on another page in the site located at (/sales) When you complete this form I just have it send you to the same thank you page.

If I just create a goal that tracks when the destination page is "thank you" then there is no way to track which form the user came from.

Can I create a Funnel (that is Required) (step 1 must be be / or /sales) would that act as a prerequisite to complete the goal? In other words, will that only track my sales form if the user actually goes to /sales, then completes the form?

I fear it will not - that the user initially goes to /, then /sales, then complete the form (ends up at 'thank you') and this would count as both goals since the funnel completed for both in theory.

Is this just not the right way to go about it, and I need to use Google Tag Manager form triggers for this? Or is there an analytics solution for this.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The funnels only affect visualization, not goal conversions, so that will not help you. If you want a conversion only with a certain referrer you need to solve that in code, e.g. by checking the referring page in your tracking code and send an event only if it matches the desired values.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I decided to use Google Tag Manager for a form submission, and setup a goal in analytics to match on the submitted form event's values (label, value, etc)